# Merging dll's for winphone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, ilmerge

I read a thread on this forum "How can I use ILMerge with Windows Phone 7 assemblies?" saying that ILMerge did not support WP7. I tried it myself, and got the same result. Does not seem to work. Unless I'm doing it all wrong!

Is there any other way to merge several dll's into one, I cannot find a tool for this (besides ILMerge, and NETZ which both seem to handle .NET only). I have a WP7 project in C# that produces 5 dll's. Would like to merge them all into a single one. Would be easier to handle for the people writing the application on top of them.

I am using the MS Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone.

Would be thankful for some advice!

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Just so we can release only one dll, instead of 5. It is not the end of the world, but would be nice if it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm managed to IL Merge WP7 assemblies and I've bogged about it [here](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-ilmerge-for-windows-phone-7.html)

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked for me..Sorry for the late feedback though!

Answer (score 0):

ILMerge has not been updated to support Windows Phone 7. It's a long shot, but [Jeffrey Richter's approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) of adding the referenced assemblies as embedded resources might work.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that article. Unfortunately there is no option for “Embedded Resource" in 'MS Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone'. And this version of visual studio is the only one that has support for wp7.

Comment: Are you sure you added the assemblies as files that are a member of the project (not as a Reference)? I don't have any problems adding dll files in a project and setting the Build Action to Embedded Resource.